# Part wise Gram-Schmidt-Scheme on a large set of Vectors

Tags: python, vector

In a Simulation i create a large set of vectors on which i apply the Gram-Schmidt scheme part wise. By part wise i mean, that i first remove the components of the vectors and then compute its length (check orth_2 or orth_3 formulas in the code below). The length is then stored to compute later a desired value (l-values, see code below). Only after that i normalize the vector.

The above explained procedure is shown in the following code for three vectors:

```
from numpy import random

N = 3                  'Numer of rows and columns. In my real case N is equal to 100'

l1, l2, l3 = 0, 0, 0   'Quantities that i want to compute. Again in my case i have 100s of them l1, l2,...,l100' 


for t in range(10**3):  'Simulate Computation' 

    ''' for i in range(10**5):

        Computation where i compute Matrix A with its vectors A[0], A[1]... '''

    A = random.rand(N, N) 'A is generated randomly to keep the code short'

   'Apply the Gram-Schmidt-Scheme on the vectors A[0], A[1], A[2]. Again in my case i have 100 vectors'

    orth_1 = A[0]                   
    l1    += log(norm(orth_1)) 
    A[0]   = orth_1 / norm(orth_1)        

    orth_2 = A[1] - dot(A[1], A[0]) * A[0] 'Remove any A[0] components from A[1]'
    l2    += log(norm(orth_2))             'Store the values that i want to compute later'
    A[1]   = orth_2 / norm(orth_2)           

    orth_3 = A[2] - (dot(A[2], A[1]) * A[1]) - (dot(A[2], A[0]) * A[0]) 'Remove any A[0] and A[1] components from A[2]'
    l3    += log(norm(orth_3)) 
    A[2]   = orth_3 / norm(orth_3)
```

As u can see the formulas for **orth_** get longer and longer as the number of vectors increases. For N = 3 is 
still doable but for N = 100 it becomes quit challenging to write out all formulas for orth_1, orth_2,..,orth_100 to compute the desired  values l1, l2,..., l100.

Does someone have an idea how i could atomize this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your original code so I could do a comparison on the answers to make sure the math worked out. I believe this function returns the same answer your code calculates.

```
def removeOrthos(Arr, N, l):
    remove = 0
    for i in range(N):
        remove -= np.dot(Arr[N], Arr[i]) * Arr[i]
    ortho = Arr[N] + remove
    l[N] += np.log(np.linalg.norm(ortho))
    return ortho / np.linalg.norm(ortho)
```

Here’s your original code with comparisons to my function and linalg.qr()

```
def ortho():
    N = 3 #                  'Numer of rows and columns. In my real case N is equal to 100'
    l1, l2, l3 = 0, 0, 0  # 'Quantities that i want to compute. Again in my case i have 100s of them l1, l2,...,l100' 
    L = np.zeros(N)
    for t in range(10**3):  #'Simulate Computation' 

#''' for i in range(10**5):
#Computation where i compute Matrix A with its vectors A[0], A[1]... '''

        A = np.random.rand(N, N) #'A is generated randomly to keep the code short'

#'Apply the Gram-Schmidt-Scheme on the vectors A[0], A[1], A[2]. Again in my case i have 100 vectors'

        B = np.copy(A)
        for b in range(N):
            B[b] = removeOrthos(B, b, L)

        Q,R = np.linalg.qr(np.copy(A).T)    
        orth_1 = A[0]                   
        l1    += np.log(np.linalg.norm(orth_1)) 
        A[0]   = orth_1 / np.linalg.norm(orth_1)        

        orth_2 = A[1] - np.dot(A[1], A[0]) * A[0] #'Remove any A[0] components from A[1]'
        l2    += np.log(np.linalg.norm(orth_2)) #             'Store the values that i want to compute later'
        A[1]   = orth_2 / np.linalg.norm(orth_2)           

        orth_3 = A[2] - (np.dot(A[2], A[1]) * A[1]) - (np.dot(A[2], A[0]) * A[0]) #'Remove any A[0] and A[1] components from A[2]'
        l3    += np.log(np.linalg.norm(orth_3)) 
        A[2]   = orth_3 / np.linalg.norm(orth_3)
    print(l1,l2,l3, L)

    return A, B, Q, R
```

Below note the False condition at [2,0] although the actual figures appear to match, there must be some rounding error beyond 7 places past the decimal.

```
>>> A, B, Q, R = ortho()
-74.2981307378 -838.247442533 -1628.34240096 [  -74.29813074  -838.24744253 -1628.34240096]
>>> A==B
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> A
array([[ 0.01225148,  0.554242  ,  0.8322654 ],
       [ 0.99376938, -0.09896161,  0.05127395],
       [ 0.1107805 ,  0.82645169, -0.55200116]])
>>> B
array([[ 0.01225148,  0.554242  ,  0.8322654 ],
       [ 0.99376938, -0.09896161,  0.05127395],
       [ 0.1107805 ,  0.82645169, -0.55200116]])
>>> A==Q
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> Q
array([[-0.01225148,  0.99376938, -0.1107805 ],
       [-0.554242  , -0.09896161, -0.82645169],
       [-0.8322654 ,  0.05127395,  0.55200116]])
```

Comment: Are u able to compute L with  pythons function linalg.qr()? Are the results are the same l1, l2, l3?

Comment: I had never used linalg.qr() before so that may be a good question for Lehmann, but the results of R from linalg.qr() in my tears were no where close to l1,l2 or l3. The removeOrthos function that I posed above does calculate the L values you require.

Comment: Yeah i know. I used your method for my case. The computation time is quite long, so i thought that i could increase by using qr() method

Comment: Did you run performance analytics against your original code and removeOrthos()? I’m just curious. I might run some later today. There are several thing that could improve performance if that is a issue. Change the for loop to list comprehension, use np.vectorize on removeOthos(), use Numba, or Cython.

Comment: Do u mean by performance analytics, the time that my computer needs to execute the code?

Comment: Yes, not sure if you are familiar with the timeit module. Very useful for checking code performance. I can post some results later if it would be helpful

Comment: You need to compare `A` with `Q.T`, undoing the transposition. Also better use `np.isclose` to compare floating point results. One also needs to remove the signs from the diagonal of `R` and apply them to `Q` to get comparable results, `S = np.diag(np.sign(np.diag(R))); R=S.dot(R); Q=Q.dot(S);`. For the intended application the orientation changes of the propagated frame have no influence on the Lyapunov exponents.

Comment: The (absolute values of the) diagonal entries of `R` are the individual `np.linalg.norm(orth_1)` etc., you can not compare them to the cumulative logarithms of the norms.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite simple solution, apply the QR decomposition that is already present in `numpy.linalg` (or `scipy.linalg`)

```
Q,R = np.linalg.qr(A.T);
```

Then in the result

```
A=R.T*Q.T
```

the columns of `Q` or, as you use it, the rows of `Q.T` contain the orthonormalized approximate eigen-vectors and the diagonal of `R` or `R.T=A*Q` contains the reduced lengths, possibly with a sign. To get the normalized QR decomposition with a positive diagonal in `R`, use

```
S = np.diag(np.sign(np.diag(R))); Q, R = Q.dot(S), S.dot(R);
```

`numpy` uses the QR routines of LAPACK, which go via the more stable Householder reflectors. But the result is, up to signs/orientations the same.

Comment: The orthogonalized vectors in Q are not normalized, correct?

Comment: Q is by the definition of the decomposition, and as a product of reflections, an orthogonal matrix. Row and column systems are orthonormal.